# How to recomiple PHP to add an extra configure option and not loose all the settings I had

Tags: php, configuration

I need to have a configuration for mssql in my PHP installation but obviously you have to recompile PHP or do you? How can you make sure all your configurations that you had added before and your php.ini stays correct if you had a bunch of stuff setup?

Comment: What do you mean by "bunch of stuff" exactly? The php.ini you should be able to copy to a safe location, and put back after recompiling. What else is there?

Comment: I meant like a lot of modules and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpinfo() will give you the exact configure command you used to compile.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, I just wasn't sure if I recompile if there was anything else that I would need to backup besides the php.ini.